# Is there any extension in Vscode in which when i select a HTML element, and all the direct children of that element will be highlighted?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image]

**For example, when i select this form tag, all it's direct children are highlighted.** 

If there aren't any, could you guys tell me how to make it work myself?

Comment: Not possible via native settings, easiest way around it would be to use code folding. But if you're persistant enough you could make it work that way with an extension or hacking the editor with CSS.

Comment: @marblewraith can we somehow use  auto close tag source code (https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag) to make it work ?

Comment: No. Over 90% of it would have to be discarded / rewritten.